# Use closure inside array with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, copy

I need to copy a string inside an array to a value inside another array that is created in a loop. In the end when I print all names are the last in the array of names. I want to copy/clone the value so that I don't have a reference and I would like it to be only in native javascript without external libraries.

This is my code

```
var exp_names =["name1","name2","name3"];
var i;    
for (i = 0; i < exp_names.length; i++) { 
    d3.tsv("data/"+exp_names[i], function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d){
           //Do stuff with my tsv
           d.expId = exp_names[i];
        });
    }); 
});
```

And then all expId are "name3"

Data is loading correctly per file.

I have tried with jquery's extend function and also lodash's clone function, I have tried my own clone function and nothing works it will still throw "name3" for all the expId.

These didn't work:

```
var newname = new String(exp_names[i]);
var newname = $.extend(true, {}, exp_names[i]);
var newname = $.extend( {}, exp_names[i]);
var newname = _.clone(exp_names[i]);
var newname = exp_names[i].slice(0);
```

I am desperate by now.

Comment: Write please the expected result from your input array exp_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function.

```
var exp_names =["name1","name2","name3"];
var i;
var func = [];    
for (i = 0; i < exp_names.length; i++) {
    func[i]=(function(index){
         d3.tsv("data/"+exp_names[index], function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(d){
               //Do stuff with my tsv
               d.expId = exp_names[index];
            });
         }); 
    }).bind(this,i);
}
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   func[i](i);
}
```

Another solution is to use `let` keyword.

> ES6 provides the let  keyword for this exact circumstance. Instead of using  closures, we can just use let to set a loop scope variable.

Please try this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < exp_names.length; i++) { 
    d3.tsv("data/"+exp_names[i], function(data) {
       data.forEach(function(d){
          //Do stuff with my tsv
          d.expId = exp_names[i];
       });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, the "let" keyword helped me very much! Bind didn't work, it didn't even made the loop, maybe I wrote something wrong. But anyway "let" saved the day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess usage of IIFE and bind together, in the first answer is a little weird. It's best to choose either one of them. Since [in the newest versions of the browsers `bind` is way faster than an IIFE closure](https://jsperf.com/simple-null-bind-vs-closure) and the `let` keyword I might suggest you the `bind` way.

A similar example to your case might be as folows;

```js
var exp_names = ["name1","name2","name3"],
          lib = {doStg: function(d,cb){
                          cb(d);
                        }
                },
         data = [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}];

for (i = 0; i < exp_names.length; i++) { 
    lib.doStg(data, function(i,d) {
                      d.forEach(function(e){
                                  //Do stuff with doStg
                                  e.expId = exp_names[i];
                                  console.log(e);
                                });
                    }.bind(null,i));
}
```